# SQL Group by many individual columns

Tags: sql, db2-400

I am not sure what to call this or what to search for. Basically I want to sum an amount by many individual columns. The only way I can think of to do this is to do a subquery for each column.

Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks

```
select q1.id, q1.amt state, q2.amt city ...
from 
 (select  id,state,sum(paid) amt
 from tableA
 group by id,state) q1
inner join 
 (select  id,city,sum(paid) amt
  from tableA
  group by id,city) q2
on q1.id = q2.id
```

Comment: Please edit your query with sample data and desired results.  Your results don't really make sense . . . You'll end up with cross products of states and cities for each id.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess that, for each `id`, you want the sum of `amt` along each dimension, such as city and state.

If so, you can use window/analytic/olap functions.  Something like:

```
select id, sum(amt) over (partition by state) as state_amt,
       sum(amt) over (partition by city) as city_amt
from tableA;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use OLAP,  I am on DB2 for iSeries for partition is not available.

Comment: The 7.1 SQL manual for DB2 for i has the OLAP specs including 'partition by'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gordon for the insight to use OLAP functions. The same OLAP functions like "partition by" are not available for db2 for i.  I ended up with this, which I will have to wrap to sum up each column

```
select id,
case when GROUPING(STATE) = 0
     then sum(PAID)
end STATE,
case when GROUPING(CITY) = 0
     then sum(PAID)
end CITY ...
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY ID, GROUPING SETS((ID,STATE),(ID,CITY)....)
```

GROUPING SETS creates records not columns for each group
GROUPING indicates what set the record belongs to (when 0)

Example:

GROUPING

```
ID  STATE CITY PAID
1A   0     1   500.00
1A   1     0   250.00
```

USING THE GROUPING TO SEE WHERE TO ALLOCATE PAID

```
ID  STATE  CITY 
1A  500.00 NULL
1A  NULL   250.00
```